# How to read data from ParseObject in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse.com and Android and I'm struggling to read data from a Parse Object. I read the documentation and downloaded the tutorials but it is not clear. I have a ParseObject named Issue and all I need is to read data from this object and display it to the user. Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_issue);


        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "QKpM7ar7aWwrbEeTcrSGJ5bDnLMCUtc1kCr26Enl", "MCBdIQ6Y0dTsIoahzJ44UfR1zHZPJMQPwiETwj47");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Issue");
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "2aRwvd1Rnv");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> issueList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("Issue", "Retrieved " + issueList.size() + " issue");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List" + issueList, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });



    }
```

I don't understand how I can read data from this ParseObject. The returned result issueList is this: List[com.parse.ParseObject@4b079f88]

And if I use issue.getString("objectId") I get an error. Please help.

Comment: First Learn about how to display data in a listView from a data source with adapter. In your case. ParseQuery will give you list of ParseObject. If you understand the first part. you can easily do this

Comment: this is the list returned from ParseObject List[com.parse.ParseObject@4b079f88]

Comment: how can I get any info from this result

Comment: Dude, how you get value from a object? there is a obj.get() method for everything

Comment: first you should check if(issueList != null) then check if its size is greater than 0. if true. do, issueList.get("column name you given in Parse table IssueList");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78765/discussion-between-shubendra-and-rori).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr. Shubendara I was able to fix this:

```
 if (issueList!=null){
                        if (issueList.size()>0){
                            for( int i = 0; i<issueList.size(); i++){
                                String o =   issueList.get(i).getString("Title");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List" + o, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
```